# How to solve the key error problem in pandas library in jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, keyerror

`When I write this code in jupyter notebook for data analysis of housing datasets using pandas and it does not run the code as the error occur.

**Code:**

```
strat_train_set = housing.iloc[train_index]
strat_test_set = housing.iloc[test_index]
```

**Key Error Messege:**

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)

3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
3808     #  the TypeError.
3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'CHAS'